# Expressing "(one's) off" as in "he is working his ass off"

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques, argot

(slang) *(One's) ass off* is used to emphasize the preceding verb as having been done to the maximum degree. For instance

> I worked my ass off to get where I am today!
>
> The people in the back were working their asses off.
>
> This comedian will make you laugh your ass off.

What are some ways to express a similar idea in French? For the first two sentences with the verb work I am thinking about

> J'ai travaillé comme un chien/comme un fou pour arriver là où je suis aujourd'hui !
>
> Les gens à l'arrière se déchirent au travail.

For the remaining sentence

> Ce comédien va te faire mourir de rire.

Are these sentences enough idiomatic and convey similar ideas with the English sentences? Any other suggestions?

Comment: On peut dire "se casser le cul". Le sens n'est pas exactement le même, mais utilise "cul"/"ass".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

À ce qui a déjà été dit, et qui est acceptable (sauf peut-être se déchirer au travail), je pense qu'il faut rajouter l'expression « comme un malade », qui veut dire beaucoup, avec excès.

À l'entrée **malade** du *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* :

> Fam. ***Comme un malade***, en se démenant, avec force. Il travaille comme un malade.→comme une bête, comme un fou.

- Faut-il travailler comme un malade pour réussir ? ([youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZuE4KDPiMvc))
- Pourquoi bosser comme un malade ne paye pas toujours.([Capital.fr](https://www.capital.fr/votre-carriere/pourquoi-bosser-comme-un-malade-ne-paye-pas-toujours-1257630))

Et l'idée de pénibilité peut être renforcée si on remplace *travailler* par *trimer*.

- Le comble c’est que cette personne a obtenu 18/20 alors que moi qui ai trimé comme un malade, je n’ai obtenu que 11/20. ([Sur un forum](https://www.europe1.fr/societe/bonnenotefr-le-site-qui-fait-scandale-dans-le-monde-de-leducation-je-savais-que-moralement-ce-serait-difficile-dexpliquer-ce-que-lon-voulait-faire-2981774))
- Je vais devoir trimer comme un malade toute ma vie pour un maigre salaire qui me procurera juste de quoi manger. ([*Le roman d'un timide*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=NZykLJGE_zkC&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq=trimer%20%22comme%20un%20malade%22&source=bl&ots=ek2sUO1Qpa&sig=ACfU3U1PtcIgk1N6PmHDX09UbO2dG-UcnQ&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjY9c2TxtfkAhXRzoUKHfcWBlAQ6AEwEHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=trimer%20%22comme%20un%20malade%22&f=false), Jean-Pierre Boghossian)

Et en plus familier encore avec *chier* :

- J’en chie tous les jours comme un malade à l’entrainement, deux fois par jour, six jours sur sept et quasiment tous les jours de l’année ([chronique du vélo](https://chroniqueduvelo.fr/pervis-jen-chie-tous-les-jours-comme-un-malade/))

On peut aussi employer l'expression avec rire :

> Voici une blague vraiment nulle, mais qui m'avait fait rire comme un malade. ([Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5PzS1_JLXCA).)

Answer (score 1):

Voici deux suggestions par une professeure de FLE pour les phrases avec le verbes work :

> Les gens à l'arrière se donnent à fond.
>
> Je me suis tué à tâche pour réussir.

Comment: C'est probablement la première suggestion qui est à l'origine d'une équivalente assez usuelle utilisant *défoncer* pronominalement : *Les gens à l'arrière se défoncent vraiment*

Answer (score 1):

The French sentences you mention are idiomatic and will be OK in all contexts, except that one:

> Les gens à l'arrière se déchirent au travail.

In an appropriate context, it may be understood thanks to the mention of *au travail* but *se déchirer*, in a metaphorical sense, rather has the meaning of *to quarrel, to fight bitterly against each other* (ex: *Les parents se déchirent depuis leur divorce pour obtenir la garde de leurs enfants*).

A more idiomatic suggestion:

> Les gens à l'arrière se tuaient à la tâche.

However, all of your suggestions are fairly neutral in terms of level of language, and do not carry the somehow vulgar connotation carried by the mention of *ass* in English.

You can find some phrases that would also refer to the "place where the sun never shines" in French too:

> Je me suis cassé le cul pour en arriver là (not exactly the same as *to work one's ass off*, it rather says you have done a lot of efforts for something, which may not necessarily involve "working" as such)
>
> J'ai adoré ce spectacle, c'était à se taper le cul par terre (means something is very funny, also if something is so ridiculous that it can be funny. Ex: j'ai écouté l'interview de Donald Trump, c'était à se taper le cul par terre)

Comment: D'accord avec toi pour « se déchirer au travail » mais on peut récupérer [déchirer, def. n° 2](https://dico-des-mots.com/definitions/ca-dechire.html) pour le comédien  : ce spectacle ça déchire !

Comment: Juste - mais alors "Déchirer" ne signifie pas alors "être drôle", mais plutôt "laisser une très forte impression" (ex: *ce concert/ce film/ce match, ça déchire*, ou *cette voiture/cette moto, elle déchire*). On pourrait a fortiori même dire que quelque chose de pas drôle du tout *déchire* (au-delà du sens de "être déchirant, émouvant"). Ex: *j'ai regardé la dernière saison de Game of Thrones, la scène où le dragon détruit toute la ville et massacre des dizaines d'innocents, ça déchire !*

Comment: Oui, bien sûr ça ne contient pas l'idée de rire, ce n'est que de la récup de mot, faut l'enrober. Et j'avais pas mis le lien vers la [réf la plus complète](https://www.dictionnairedelazone.fr/dictionary/definition/dechirer) pas pour toi, mais pour Dimitris s'il ne connait pas encore.